# replicate subquery in PowerBI

Tags: merge, powerbi-desktop, lookup-tables

I have two tables:
[image]

The merge is on the `field name` value of the JLE_LineTypeCategory matching the `Type` and `Line Type` columns on JobLedgerEntry. In SQL, I would do something like this:

```
 SELECT optiontext 
    FROM metadataTable md
    WHERE TableName='JobLedgerEntry' 
        AND FieldName='LineType' 
        AND md.OptionInteger=JobLedgerEntry.[Type]
) as 'Type'
```

but I'm not sure how to do that in BI. Basically, I'm looking at the value of a field in the `JLE_LineTypeCategory` table to match with the column name in the `JobLedgerEntry` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I only needed one set of field descriptors, I filtered the LineTypeCategory table to just the 3 possible values for the JobLedgerEntry.LineType field. I then merged the two tables on the optionInteger-LineType fields.